# Retrofit send Json object and get List as response

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I send to my service json object like this

```
{
  "procedure_name": "testowa",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "Id": "1"
    }

  ]
}
```

As a response I get resultset of my sql procedure on the same url:

```
[
 {"id": 1, "email": "test", "password": "test"}

]
```

To do that i write this code. 
This is my api interface:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("/")
    Call<Object> getData(@Body Procedure procedure);
}
```

And this is my procedure class:

```
public class Procedure
{
    final String procedure_name;
    final List<HashMap<String, String>> parameters;

    public Procedure(String procedure_name, List<HashMap<String, String>> parameters)
    {
        this.procedure_name = procedure_name;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

And at the end MainActivity part where I save the response

```
ApiInterface service = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

    HashMap<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();
    parameter.put("id", "1");

    List<HashMap<String, String>> list_parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    list_parameters.add(parameter);


    Procedure procedure = new Procedure("testowa", list_parameters);
    Call<Object> call = service.getData(procedure);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
            String apiResponse = new Gson().toJson(response.body());
            textViewResult.append(apiResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
            textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I save a response like a string, but  I want to save this like List of objects. I should create one more class maybe User and save response as a list of objects this class. But I don't know how to change my api interface and other methods  to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to create a POJO based on your API response, something like this:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.*;

public class User {

@Expose
private Integer id;
@Expose
private String email;
@Expose
private String password;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

}
```

Then, if you didnt' already done, you should pass a Gson builder to your Retrofit instance creation, something like this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("apiEndpoint/url")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
```

Then you have to adapt your retrofit API accordingly to receive a list of Users just like a JSOn array:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@POST("/")
Call<List<User>> getData(@Body Procedure procedure);
}
```

Finally, retrofit will provide you the response in a POJO form:

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
        List<User> apiResponse =response.body();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
        textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Straight forward 'http://jsonschema2pojo.org/' can help you generate POJO from Api Responses. Once you get your generated POJO, replace the 'Object' type in the Api interface method with the POJO class. You will also need to change the CallBack response type to the generated POJO class

Answer (score -1):

I send to my service json object like this

{
  "procedure_name": "testowa",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "Id": "1"
    }

]
}

// For this Request, You need to use this class -

```
 public class myRequest{
String procedure_name;
ArrayList<myObject> parameters;

        public String getProcedure_name() {
            return procedure_name;
        }

        public void setProcedure_name(String procedure_name) {
            this.procedure_name = procedure_name;
        }

        public ArrayList<myObject> getParameters() {
            return parameters;
        }

        public void setParameters(ArrayList<myObject> parameters) {
            this.parameters = parameters;
        }

        public myRequest() {
        }

        public myRequest(String procedure_name, ArrayList<myObject> parameters) {
            this.procedure_name = procedure_name;
            this.parameters = parameters;
        }

        public class myObject{

            String Id;

            public String getId() {
                return Id;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                Id = id;
            }

            public myObject() {
            }

            public myObject(String id) {
                Id = id;
            }
        }
    }
```

And Change this to :

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("/")
    Call<Object> getData(@Body myRequest myRequest);
}
```

And in your activity or Fragment do this to call :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>;
list.add("1");
 myRequest myRequest = new myRequest ("testowa", list);

 Call<Object> call = service.getData(myRequest );
```

it will work .